# How to cache service worker source file at least for 24hour

Tags: caching, browser-cache, service-worker, cache-control, service-worker-events

Is there any possibility to cache service worker source file for at least 24 hours? I have tried providing cache-control: public, max-age=1440. but it's not working.

Also, If a page contains an iframe and if you reload that iframe alone, sw.js(service worker script) is getting downloaded from the server.

Any idea why this is happening? How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is due to the behavior described in "[Fresher service workers, by default](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw)."

In particular, if you want to opt-in to using the HTTP cache to satisfy your service worker requests (for up to 24 hours; after than, they'll always go against the network), you can use code like:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
    updateViaCache: 'all',
  });
}
```